# LuaXML error when parsing certain XML files

Tags: xml, parsing, lua

I having a peculiar error when trying to parse a directory with XML files.

For whatever reason, some files parse just fine and I have no issues, but for whatever reason I receive this error when trying to parse some XML files:

LuaXML 'XMLDecl not at start of document [char=1]'

I looked at another post with the same issue and I tried following his fix of changing encoding to encode and the error still seems to persist regardless.

I checked through the files that give me errors when trying to parse and I don't know what is wrong with their header as they seem to be identical to the headers that are working.

here is what my parsing code looks like:

```
local filename = "fdsqwe.xml"
local xmltext = ""
local f, e = io.open(filename,"r")

if f then
  xmltext = f:read("*a")
else
  error(e)
end

local xmlhandler = simpleTreeHandler()
local xmlparser = xmlParser(xmlhandler)
xmlparser:parse(xmltext)
```

and here is what the headers look like for the XML files:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Any help or potential insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you change the file's encoding or just the entry in the XML header? can you share such a file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the file, and I believe I just changed the header.  I believe these XML documents are simply incorrectly formatted or improperly encoded as they are the only two out of many XML files that are giving me this error.

Comment: you cannot change a file's encoding by changing the encoding-attribute in the header. download notepad ++, open the file, convert it to utf-8 and then try again. also make sure you print the xmltext string for those files and check its contents

Comment: From a shell prompt (not a Lua prompt) try `hexdump -C fdsqwe.xml | head -n 10`.  Compare the first couple of lines of this output for working and non-working files.